# Server side cursor support in MySQL JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, rdbms

MySQL Connector-J Documentation ([here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-implementation-notes.html)) mentions two ways in which the JDBC retrieves results from the MySQL database. One is the default operation, in which the entire result set is loaded into memory and made accessible in the code. The second is row by row streaming.

I would like to know whether the latest versions of MySQL/MySQL JDBC support server side cursors. Specifically, I would like to know whether the options `useCursorFetch=True` and `defaultFetchSize>0` can be used to ensure that the result set is retrieved from the database in batches of certain size (fetch size). MySQL describes server side cursors in its C API ([here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cursor-restrictions.html)), and I would like to know whether similar support is there with MySQL JDBC.

If this support exists, what are the constraints of such an operation? I understand that a temporary table would be created in the server's memory from which results would be fetched. But what are the other things to look out for (such as table/row locks, restrictions on update/insertions, and result set/connection closing)?

Answer (score 1):

The most recent version of the documentation you [linked to](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-implementation-notes.html) has this note:

> By default, ResultSets are completely retrieved and stored in memory. [...] you can tell the driver to stream the results back one row at a time.
>
> To enable this functionality, create a Statement instance in the following manner:

```
stmt = conn.createStatement(java.sql.ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY,
          java.sql.ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
stmt.setFetchSize(Integer.MIN_VALUE);
```

This sounds like what you're looking for.

Comment: It's important to note that fetch sizes like 2000 (which feels pretty meaningful low) - do not work: I got OOM. Apparently, there is special check for value Integer.MIN_VALUE that enables real streaming mode.